# Load client Javascript and CSS in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to load client side javascript `chat.js`and css `style.css` in my html file but i get a `404` error while loading them.

This is my server file:

```
// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

This is my client html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="chat.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

How can I load them in my app?
All files are in the same root folder.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.js');
});
```

Comment: You should read an express beginners tutorial / getting started guide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using express web framework so in that case you should use the [express static middleware](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) for your purposes.

I did an example that is below.

here is the server `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(4040, function() {
  console.log('server up and running');
});
```

Where you see that Express is serving the files that resides on `public` directory.
You see I didn't provide a route for `/` since the browser automatically is going to grab the `index.html`.

---

`public/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hey</h1>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

From the perspective of the browser he only knows the `index.html`, `app.js`, and `style.css` files since they were provided by express.

---

`public/style.css`:

```
body {                                                          
    background: red;                                            
}
```

---

`public/app.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  alert('hello world');
});
```